DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found , win32com.client python library
when I import the win32com.client module i get this error
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found 
the line producing the error is :
\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py line 118 in __pywin32_system_module__ mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec) 
when i print the spec variable that is defined just above that line i see that it contains the correct path to the dll:
ModuleSpec(name='pywintypes', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x0000020060A79208>, origin='C:\\Users\\ilyes\\Documents\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32\\pywintypes37.dll') 
just wanted to clarify , i installed the pywin32 library , both pythoncom37.dll, pywintypes37.dll are found on venv\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\
System information
Python version and distribution:
python3.7 , windows
pywin32 version:
pywin32==306 installed via pip
Windows Version:
windows 10 22H2 19045.4412 installed on virtual machine
win32com.client module cannot be imported even if when I correctly installed pywin32 library

It may not be that it can't find pywintypes37.dll. The issue may be it can't find a dll that pywintypes37.dll needs. How to check for DLL dependency?

@001 I'm sure it is wanting pywintypes37.dll because I saw the code that is executing and modfied it to print the dll it was looking for when the error happened, and it indeed was pywintypes37.dll
